# WCF Routing with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two WCF service named as `calculator and routing service`. `Calculator service` will not be explore outside world, so I call the `calculator service` from the routing service. In this I have used the Windows authentication for `routing service` but I can't able to get the client credentials in calculator service.

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that we need to pass the credentials in the header user the message inspector from the routing service.